# Combinatorics involving heights

Tags: combinatorics

There are $6$ persons with different heights. They are to be seated in $2$ rows with a capacity of $3$ each in such a way that the person sitting behind the other is taller than the person in front. In how many ways can this be done?

I tried working this way: intially found the total number of ways in which the persons can be arranged ie $6P3 * 3P3= 720$
so there can be two possibilities: either the person in front is taller or shorter. therefore i could've found my answer by dividing the total number of ways by $2$. ie $720/2=360$

But then somebody explained that this was wrong, the correct way would be to work for a pair of seats (ie front and back) $6C2 * 1$ (selecting $2$ persons from $6$ and they can be arranged only in one way)
therefore, for all $3$ seats, it'll be like: $6C2*1*4C2*1*2C2*1=90$
But $90$ and $360$ aren't the same, so which is correct and why?

Comment: The answer I come to: The shortest person must be on the first row.  Pick which column (3 choices).  Pick someone to stand behind him (5 choices).  The shortest remaining person must be on the first row.  Pick which column (2 choices).  Pick someone to stand behind him (3 choices).  The remaining two people have only one way to arrange themselves in the remaining spots.  This gives $3\cdot 5\cdot 2\cdot 3 = 90$ options.

Comment: In your approach, you divided only by two., which accounts for the first column of people, but you neglected the second column and the third column.  If you had continued to divide by two twice more you would have arrived at the correct answer of $90$.  In either case, I prefer to avoid answers which rely on division by symmetry arguments as those frequently confuse students (*as is apparently the case here*).

Comment: Thank you, the way you calculated the answer: how do you account for the height of the person? That is, how do you clearly fulfill the height criteria, can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: actually, i think i got your answer. But what would happen if take the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 instead of people and arrange in the same condition?

Comment: Assuming a smaller number must be placed in front of a larger number, we have three ways to place the number $1$ in the first row and five ways to place a larger number behind $1$.  That leaves us with four numbers to place.  The smallest of them must be placed in the first row.  There are two ways to place it.  There are three ways to choose the number that is behind it.  That leaves us with two numbers.  The smaller must be placed in the remaining position in the first row and the larger must be placed behind it.  Hence, there are $3 \cdot 5 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 = 90$ permissible arrangements.